# Copy from const char* to a byte array C++/c# interop Marshal::Copy

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, marshalling

I'm trying to send an image from C++ to C# with an interop (marshaling) of C++ managed. `image->getStream()` return a `const char*` from a string.

I'm having exception with my `Marshal::Copy` function.

> An unhandled exception of type `'System.AccessViolationException'` occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Am I doing the right thing for the copy from a `const char*` to a byte array ? My dll is compiled with ASCII char set in VS2010.

```cpp
array<System::Byte>^ OsgViewer::getLastImage()
{
    array< Byte >^ byteArray;

    m_ImageQueue->lock();

    int index = m_ImageQueue->getCurrentImageIndex();
    std::shared_ptr<Image> image = m_ImageQueue->getImage(static_cast<unsigned int>(index));
    if( image && image->isValid() == true)
    {
        int wLen = image->getStreamSize();
        char* wStream = const_cast<char*>(image->getStream());
        byteArray = gcnew array< Byte >(wLen);

        // convert native pointer to System::IntPtr with C-Style cast
        Marshal::Copy((IntPtr)wStream ,byteArray , 0, wLen);
    }

    m_ImageQueue->unlock();
    return byteArray;
}
```

Image is a home made C++ class

```cpp
class ADAPTER Image
{
public :
    Image();
    ~Image();
    const char* getStream() const;
    int getStreamSize();
    bool setStringStream(std::ostringstream* iStringStream);
    void setIsValid(bool isValid){ m_isValid = isValid;}
    bool isValid() const{return m_isValid;}
    std::ostringstream* getOStringStream() {return m_StringStream;}
private:
    std::ostringstream* m_StringStream;
    bool m_isValid;
};
```

Comment: What type is Image?  A System.Drawing.Image, that doesn't have a getStream() or getStreamSize().  I think the root of your problem though is that a stream is not a byte array.

Comment: See the code above, I posted the image code

Comment: My guess is that `wStream` isn't the `wLen` bytes length.  Can't really tell from you have.  If you add `char temp = wStream[wLen-1]` do you get an access violation.

Comment: You are right, it crash some times on the temp = wStream[wLen-1]

Comment: Then the `char*` you are returning from getStream() isn't `wLen` bytes long.  You'll need to see why there is a difference between the return value of `getStreamSize()` and `getStream()`

Comment: Thank's for your answers. The problem was that my wStream was a pointer to a local const char* returned by a ostringstream.str().c_str(). I didn't now that str() return a buffer copy !.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't use Marshal::Copy.  Since you have the array locally, why not just pin it and use `memcpy`?

```
pin_ptr<Byte> ptrBuffer = &byteArray[byteArray->GetLowerBound(0)];
```

You can now call `memcpy` to `ptrBuffer`.

When the scope ends the pinning is automatically undone.

Comment: Do this, it's far faster than Marshal.Copy, and shouldn't hurt the GC at all, as @AresAvatar said, it will automatically be unpinned as soon as it loses scope.

Comment: Thank's you for the answers. I used memcpy. I make a copy to byteArray directly. memcpy(byteArray,wStream,wLen). the problem was that my wStream was a pointer to a local const char* returned by a ostringstream.str().c_str(). I didn't now that str() return a buffer copy !.